# Are there any linq-to-sql for Databases other than MS-SQL?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, linq-to-sql, data-binding

I am wondering if it is possible to use Linq functionality to connect to a database like my-sql

If it is possible are you able to use the designer to created the DataAccessLayer like with MS-SQL or do you have to hand code its content.

Thanks in advance.
KJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq to Sql only works with MS-SQL.  Entity Framework can access several different database back ends and it fully supports linq.  NHibernate can access more databases but it's linq support is not yet complete.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [IQToolkit](http://iqtoolkit.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah check this out
http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/

There has been a few posts just recently on this too, just search on stackoverflow for more details.